# Use GuzzleHttp to create post request

Tags: guzzle, guzzle6

I want to create post request to a webapp that does not have API endpoints.

I want to be able to login, fetch data and post data. I have just stumbled upon GuzzleHttp, but HTTP alone is so hard. The webapp is a laravel application. How can I do this? Or is there elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte). It uses Guzzle under the hood, but provides higher level interface to deal with web sites.